# dynamic resize fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change the width of a fragment I'm using in my MaiActivity? But I can't find its `LayoutParams` for changing its default width:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int widthFfragment = 300;

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthTot = size.x;
        heightTot = size.y;

        findViewById(R.id.f1).getLayoutParams().width = widthTot-widthFfragment;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment's code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/f1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#330000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by working with the LayoutParams instance of the View obtained from Fragment.getView(). My sample code:

```
private void resizeFragment(Fragment f, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    if (f != null) {
        View view = f.getView();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
        view.setLayoutParams(p);
        view.requestLayout();       


    }
}
```

And may be used as follows:

```
resizeFragment(myFragment, 200, 500);
resizeFragment(otherFragment, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your right, the Fragment does not have LayoutParams because it is a conceptual container, you either need to adjust the layout params of the inflated view in the fragment, or to the container you attach the fragment to.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    // TODO Adjust layout params of inflated view here

    return view;
}
```

The example assumes you are inflating a ViewGroup.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I need adjust in the main activity, is it possible?

Comment: I solve it with LayoutParams and set the appropriate size.  thanks a lot